# Why is my Hosts file not loading the website on Google Cloud Hosting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, cloudflare

We have setup Google Cloud Hosting (GCH) to trial our website on there.

An old domain was used and setup with Wordpress on GCH.  that works fine.  The domain is SSL and runs.

So we did a full replace of old domain for the one we intended to use.

Then updated the hosts file on Windows PC to point ot the domain we intended to use.  The Two fields in the WP Options tables are correct.

Yet, the site won't load.
It usually done.  IP www.domain.com domain.com.

But it won't.  Tried to just use this to look at the Logo on the server, and that won't load either, so it's not Wordpress playing games.

We thought it was something wrong with the IP, but Cloudflare is pointing the old temporary domain to that IP and it's fine.

So we are a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is reachable (through the old name) then we can rule out the infrastructure (GCP)

The configuration in your host file should take preference over any DNS configuration, a couple of questions.

1. Did you close all browser windows?
2. Did you clear your browser cache?

To properly change your site domain name please take into consideration the following:

Change your domain name in within [WordPress](https://wpengine.com/resources/change-domains-wordpress/)

[Redirect visitiors](https://www.stepforth.com/resources/web-marketing-knowledgebase/how-to-redirect-an-old-domain-to-a-new-domain/) from your old site to the new site

[Update](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-Managing-DNS-records-in-Cloudflare) your DNS records accordingly